# Browser printing from a page loaded with iframe html is not paginating correctly (text lines a split at page breaks)

Tags: html, css, iframe, printing

I am using the html iframe tag to display a several page html document. When attempting to print the document with the browser, the pagination is screwed up and the page breaks displaying half of the text line on one page and then the other half on the next.

When I display the several page document directly by a url to the page, the page displays the same and correctly paginates.

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

below is the code the display the document with the iframe:

```
<style>
.h_iframe iframe {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  display: block;
}

<script>

function iframeLoaded() {
    var iFrameID = document.getElementById('iframe');
    if(iFrameID) {
          iFrameID.height = "";
          var height = iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
          iFrameID.height = height + "px";
    }   
}
</script>

<body>
<div class="h_iframe">
    <iframe src='anyfilename.htm' name="iframe" id="iframe" onload="iframeLoaded()" scrolling='no' allowfullscreen frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

and in anyfilename.htm the following in the style section: (however as I mentioned above printing this file directly properly paginates the document.

```
@media print {

    .site-container, .site-inner , body {position:relative;}

  p {
      page-break-before: auto;
      page-break-after: auto; 
      page-break-inside: avoid;
      display: block;
      position: relative; 
  }

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated